# OpenSans package doesn't affect title (scrartcl)

Tags: fonts, sectioning, koma-script, sans-serif, scrartcl

I intend to set Open Sans as the entire document's font.

However, if I use the `opensans` package with the `default` option it doesn't affect the title and headings of the `scrartcl` class.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[default]{opensans}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Title and subtitle are still in Computer Modern. How can I change them to also appear in OpenSans?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the option `defaultsans` when loading the package:

```
\usepackage[defaultsans,default]{opensans}
```

[image]

Comment: Or pass the option `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles` to `scrartcl`.

Comment: @egreg that does the job, but doesn't really fit this type of usage, does it? ;)

Comment: There are reasons why that's my favorite option with koma classes. ;-)

Comment: In case someone reading this wants more explanation for what’s going on: LaTeX sets a default font family and a default sans-serif font family. `\usepackage[default]{opensans}` sets `\familydefault`, and the `defaultsans` option sets `\sfdefault` as well. The Koma classes, by default, use the sans-serif font for titles.

Comment: If your font package does not come with options to set both, you can `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}` or (much more rarely) `\renewcommand\sfdefault{\familydefault}`.